# Filling ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, fill, android-bluetooth

First of all.... HappyNew Year!!!! I'm starting to learn about Android programming and actually I'm trying to develop some code. Main idea is to search for Paired Bluetooth devices and also list all BT devices near... later I'll try to connect both devices but time to time :P

My problem is supposed to be easy because I fill my ListView with the paired ones but using this code I can't fill the one's I discover... But I don't know what I'm doing wrong cause Toast.MakeText shows this BT devices but not in the ListView.... Anyone can help me??? Many Thanks

//SHOW ANDROID VERSION
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

```
    //Setting up for JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {

        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

        if (bluetoothManager != null)
        {
             mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager .getAdapter();
        }
    } else {

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    //Enable
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    }
    //Discover my BT
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    //Paired Devices
    pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    final ArrayList<String> listBT = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView lv  =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDevicesFound);
    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        listBT.add(bt.getName());

    //Starting Search
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                listBT.add(device.getName()); //Something happens but not adding to ListView
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), device.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    //Show ListView
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , listBT));
```

Comment: I think you items are added to *listBT* but not to your listView *lv*. You must update your list adapter data *onReceive()* method. Try to add this line: *lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , listBT));* before the toast, it will create a new adapter with you new values. PS: it will be better if you change your adapter as class variable.

Comment: Thx for yor answer Rami! It works! So.. can you give me an idea about changing my adapter as a class variable? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class variable for your adapter (above in your class):

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> mDeviceListAdapter;
```

Crete the adapter and set it to the list:

```
//Show ListView
    mDeviceListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , listBT);
    lv.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
```

Update the adapter data when you have a new item:

```
 @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                listBT.add(device.getName()); 
                if(mDeviceListAdapter!=null){
                    mDeviceListAdapter.add(device.getName());
                    mDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), device.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```